# Как спарсить новости с сайта по списку ссылок и пропустить удаленные новости

Tags: python, парсер, итераторы

Подскажите как сделать итерацию из файла, в котором url ссылки на новости и сформировать json файл, в котором помимо ссылки будет описание новости и дата (это в коде уже есть). Проблема в том, что некоторые ссылки уже недоступны. Также необходимо задать время для парсинга одной ссылки и если время превышено(нужно для задания), то продолжить итерацию, т.е. чтение следующей ссылки из файла.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def check_news():
    with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
        for url in file:
            r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
            daily_block = soup.find_all("a", class_="daily-block l-item")
            news_dict = {}
    
        for title in daily_block:
            daily_title = title.find("p", class_="news-title").text.strip()
            daily_url = f'https://news.ru{title.get("href")}'
            daily_time = title.find("p", class_='news-date').text.strip()
            dayli_day = daily_url.split("/")[-2]
            dayli_month = daily_url.split("/")[-3]
            dayli_year = daily_url.split("/")[-4]
            daily_id = daily_url.split("/")[-1]
        
            news_dict[daily_id] = {
                "dayli_day": dayli_day,
                "dayli_month": dayli_month,
                "dayli_year": dayli_year,
                "daily_time": daily_time,
                "daily_title": daily_title,
                "daily_url": daily_url
            }
```

Comment: какой признак у "недоступной" ссылки?

Comment: Violet, ошибка 404

Comment: Проверка на "доступность" ссылки - `if r.status_code == 200` Код 200 означает что все ок, если например код 404 - то страница не найдена